# is it possible in Elixir to make a http POST request pushing some data to an external URL?

Tags: elixir

I have an external URL (third party code) that I want to POST some data to, I don't have to wait for a response.

How would I do this in Elixir (if possible at all?)

Effectively I want to cURL some data to an external url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/myfreeweb/httpotion

looks as if it will solve my problem :) thanks google!

EDIT: also -> https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison

Comment: When reading 'Programming Elixir' by Dave Thomas he uses httpoison in some of his examples. Seems like a simple library to get started with

Comment: I've used it now, I used it in my ExUnit tests to test my Phoenix routes. works brilliantly!

Comment: If you want to test your controller actions, you could use `Phoenix.ConnTest` helper. It makes testing your controllers much easier. A sample test would look like `get conn(), "/", some: "param"`. You could read more here: http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/benoitc/hackney is really good. I use it a lot.

Comment: HTTPPoison is built on top of hackney, more elixir less erlang for my brain :)